# Fetch value from child's child nodes

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml structure as below and i try to fetch nodes using linq to xml. I am kind of stuck how to read child's child node also I will have to get all child2 node values as coma separated values. And also have to read any dynamic nodes present under child node.
Here are sample xml's.

File 1:

```
<parent>
 <doc>
  <order>testorder</order>
   <preorder>yes</preorder>
    <child>
     <childs1>
      <child2>abc</child2>
      <child2>efg</child2>
     </childs1>
     <preview>current</preview>
     <provision>enable</provision>
    </child>
   </doc>
  </parent>
```

File 2 :

```
<parent>
 <doc>
  <order>testorder</order>
   <preorder>yes</preorder>
    <child>
     <preview>current</preview>
     <provision>enable</provision>
     <other>abc</other>
    </child>
  </doc>
 </parent>
```

My sudo code :

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
var customers =
from cust in xdoc.Descendants("doc")
      select new 
        {
        Title = cust.Element("order").Value,
        preorder = cust.Element("preorder").Value,
        innernode= from inner in cust.Elements("child")
                                  select new {
                                      site = (inner.Element("preview") != null) ? inner.Element("preview").Value : null,
                                      node=(inner.Element("childs1") != null) ?  string.Join(",",  from seg in inner.Elements("child2") select seg.Value) :null,
                              Should store if any extra dynamic nodes are there ,
                                     },
                         };
                          foreach(var item in customers)
                        {
                                               // read all nodes
                        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "I will have to get all child2 node values as coma separated". Who's "childs1" and "child2"?

Comment: Sorry missed to add my xml file 1 which had childs1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to fetch `child2` is trying to look in `doc`'s descendants, but you want to look at `childs1`'s descendants. As for dynamic fields you can do it by creating a dictionary to get any elements that don't match the hardcoded ones, as i did below.

```
var customers =
    from cust in xdoc.Descendants("doc")
    select new
    {
        Title = cust.Element("order").Value,
        preorder = cust.Element("preorder").Value,
        innernode = from inner in cust.Elements("child")
                    select new
                    {
                        site = (inner.Element("preview") != null) ? inner.Element("preview").Value : null,
                        node = (inner.Element("childs1") != null) ? string.Join(",", from seg in inner.Elements("childs1").Elements("child2") select seg.Value) : null,
                        dynamicElements = inner.Elements()?.Where(e => e.Name != "preview" && e.Name != "childs1")?.ToDictionary(e => e.Name, e => e.Value)
                    },
    };
```

Comment: I'm getting the error with the dynamicElements: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Did you copy the exact code? That error happens when you don't choose a name. In that case, the member has a name (dynamicElements). I tested that code and it's working fine, can you send the code where you're getting this error so I can test?

Comment: Reading the values from dynamicelements as below which is not working.                                                                                              foreach (var innernode in node.inner)
                                {
                                    string a = innernode.site;
                                         string node= innernode.site;
                                    OtherSpecs = innernode.dynamicElements ;


                                }